# Controller actions appearing in "artisan route:list" as Closures

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm at a loss.  I'm working on upgrading an application to Laravel 5.4, but on the way (5.2.45) I've got something weird happening with several routes.  I had 3 `Route::controller()` calls in `routes.php`, and I've converted all of them to explicit routes since `::controller()` has been dropped.  Now the new routes from one of the `::controller()` calls are working fine, the routes from the other two are not, reporting action not found.

Looking at examples, here's one that is working:

```
\Route::get( 'account/edit', array( 'as'=>'account.edit', 'uses'=>'AccountController@getEdit' ) );
```

and here is one that is not:

```
\Route::get( 'recent/clear', array( 'as'=>'recent.clear', 'use'=>'RecentController@getClear' ) );
```

For completeness sake, here are the applicable Controller sections

```
class AccountController extends Controller {

    public function getEdit()
    {
        $roles = Role::getSelectList(); 
        $districts = District::getSelectList();
        return \View::make('accountedit', array( 'editUser' => \Auth::user(), 'roles'=>$roles, 'districts'=>$districts ));
    }
}


class RecentController extends Controller {

    public function getClear()
    {
        \Session::forget( 'recent' );
        return \Redirect::to('/main')->with( array( 'alerts'=>array( ErrorHelper::alert('success','Success','The Recent list has been cleared.') ) ) );
    }
}
```

The most direct sign something weird is going on is when I run `artisan route:list`.  Here are the two applicable lines from the results:

```
| Method    | URI           | Name                            | Action                                          |
+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| GET|HEAD  | account/edit  | account.edit                    | App\Http\Controllers\AccountController@getEdit  |
| GET|HEAD  | recent/clear  | recent.clear                    | Closure                                         |
```

I have no idea why `recent.clear` is showing up as a Closure.  Any thoughts as to what's wrong?  FWIW, I have identical namespacing on both controllers, which are both in the Http\Controllers directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh heck, uses vs. use.  In the words of Grover, "I am so embarrassed..."